# missing scrollbars or missing limitation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got [this page](https://lodysreizen.nl/toonverslag.html) which shows horizontal scrollbars.

When I use javascript to load that page into a div I lose the scrollbars. Can anybody tell me how to get the scrollbars to show?
https://lodysreizen.nl/ press the "Verslag" button to get to the loaded page wihtout the scrollbars.

This is the code I use to load a page into my middiv:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".knop").on("click",function(e) {
  console.log("knop " + $(this).name)
    $("#middiv").load($(this).attr("name") + ".html")
  });
});
```

In this case the toonverslag.html

Comment: Can you just put overflow:scroll on `middiv`? Also, do you mean vertical scrollbars? I don't see horizontal ones on your example page.

Answer (score 0):

```
#middiv{
overflow-x: hidden; 
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ik need the vertical scrollbars. At the moment my text goed beont the background map.

Ik use this code:

```
<style>
.scrollbarclass {
    height:150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>
```

To make a class which I add to my midddiv. But I think that because I load a text file into my middiv:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#middiv").load("verslag.text");
});
</script>
```

the scrollbar class get lost